# This is not work Flask Rq Queue with SqlAlchemy database table

Tags: flask, heroku, redis, sqlalchemy, rq

I Have a Flask project. Process are work normal. Database is PostgreSql. Everything is working on this Database. But when I Can use Python Rq I dont reach tables with SqlAlchemy. My project is on heroku. How can i solve this problem.

**Note**:( queuing operations are working normally except database)

***init*.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager

import os
import redis
from rq import Queue
from worker import conn
#from models import User, Processed, Wallet,LogsRecord

 

# init SQLAlchemy so we can use it later in our models
db = SQLAlchemy()
q = Queue(connection=conn)
 
 

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__) # creates the Flask instance, __name__ is the name of the current Python module
  
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '****' # it is used by Flask and extensions to keep data safe
    #app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite' #it is the path where the SQLite database file will be saved
      
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://*****@e****.compute**.m**.com:5432/**' 

    #app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres:*****' #local
    
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = True # deactivate Flask-SQLAlchemy track modifications



    db.init_app(app) # Initialiaze sqlite database
   
    # The login manager contains the code that lets your application and Flask-Login work together
    login_manager = LoginManager() # Create a Login Manager instance
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login' # define the redirection path when login required and we attempt to access without being logged in
    login_manager.init_app(app) # configure it for login
    from models import User
    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id): #reload user object from the user ID stored in the session
        # since the user_id is just the primary key of our user table, use it in the query for the user
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))
    # blueprint for auth routes in our app
    # blueprint allow you to orgnize your flask app
    from auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)
    # blueprint for non-auth parts of app
    from main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    app.register_blueprint()

    
    
    return app
```

**Worker.py**

```
import os

import redis
from rq import Worker, Queue, Connection
 
listen = ['high', 'default', 'low']

redis_url = os.getenv('REDISTOGO_URL', 'redis://localhost:6379')

conn = redis.from_url(redis_url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Connection(conn):
        worker = Worker(map(Queue, listen))
        worker.work()
```

**Main.py**

```
@main.route('/test') # profile page that return 'profile'
def test():

    if request.args.get("n"):
     
        job= q.enqueue(background_task, request.args.get("n"))
   

    return render_template('test.html',veri=job.get_id)


def background_task(n):
    
    user_check = User.query.get(1)
    if(user_check):
        n=int(n)
        email=user_check.email
        start = time.time()
        for i in range(n):
            print("sayı sayıyor:",i," Kul:",email)
            time.sleep(1)
        end = time.time()     
        sure = (end-start)
    return f"Son Sayı {n} İşlem şu kadar sürdü {sure}"
```

**bash (heroku logs --tail) code Error result**

```
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034922+00:00 app[worker.1]: 22:09:07 Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034947+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1008, in __call__
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034949+00:00 app[worker.1]: return self.registry[key]
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034949+00:00 app[worker.1]: KeyError: <greenlet.greenlet object at 0x7f60ec8853b0 (otid=0x7f60ec890f80) current active started main>
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034951+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034952+00:00 app[worker.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034952+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034952+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034953+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 1031, in perform_job  
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034953+00:00 app[worker.1]: rv = job.perform()
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034954+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 749, in perform
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034955+00:00 app[worker.1]: self._result = self._execute()
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034955+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 772, in _execute
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034956+00:00 app[worker.1]: result = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034957+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/main.py", line 43, in background_task
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034957+00:00 app[worker.1]: user_check = User.query.get(1)
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034958+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 552, in __get__
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034958+00:00 app[worker.1]: return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034959+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 129, in __call__
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034959+00:00 app[worker.1]: return self.registry()
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034960+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1010, in __call__
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034960+00:00 app[worker.1]: return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034961+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4089, in 
__call__
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034961+00:00 app[worker.1]: return self.class_(**local_kw)
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034961+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 174, in __init__
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034962+00:00 app[worker.1]: self.app = app = db.get_app()
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034962+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1042, 
in get_app
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034963+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise RuntimeError(
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034964+00:00 app[worker.1]: RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034964+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034965+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1008, in __call__
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034965+00:00 app[worker.1]: return self.registry[key]
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034965+00:00 app[worker.1]: KeyError: <greenlet.greenlet object at 0x7f60ec8853b0 (otid=0x7f60ec890f80) current active started main>
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034966+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034966+00:00 app[worker.1]: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034967+00:00 app[worker.1]:
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034967+00:00 app[worker.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034967+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rq/worker.py", line 1031, in perform_job  
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034968+00:00 app[worker.1]: rv = job.perform()
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034968+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 749, in perform
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034969+00:00 app[worker.1]: self._result = self._execute()
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034969+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rq/job.py", line 772, in _execute
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034969+00:00 app[worker.1]: result = self.func(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034970+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/main.py", line 43, in background_task
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034970+00:00 app[worker.1]: user_check = User.query.get(1)
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034971+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 552, in __get__
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034971+00:00 app[worker.1]: return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034972+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 129, in __call__
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034972+00:00 app[worker.1]: return self.registry()
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034972+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1010, in __call__
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034973+00:00 app[worker.1]: return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034973+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 4089, in 
__call__
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034974+00:00 app[worker.1]: return self.class_(**local_kw)
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034974+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 174, in __init__
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034974+00:00 app[worker.1]: self.app = app = db.get_app()
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034981+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1042, 
in get_app
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034982+00:00 app[worker.1]: raise RuntimeError(
2021-07-08T22:09:07.034982+00:00 app[worker.1]: RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
```

Comment: An hour with the chapter in the Flask Mega Tutorial that introduces Rq might save you significant pain. The "Task Helpers" section in particular.
https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-xxii-background-jobs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is not with redis or database. The error says

> No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context
>
> RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.
>
> This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that
> needed to interface with the current application object in some way.
> To solve this, set up an application context with app.app_context().

In your case you have to use

```
with app.app_context():
    user_check = User.query.get(1)
if(user_check):
    [...]
```

For this you need to import your app, In your case, It is `main` as I see the route `\test` so  you have to use `main` in place of `app`, `with main.app_context():`

Comment: Thank you.  app.app_context(): should have occurred to me. Maybe I should run this code in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I did this for solution. Note to history for those who get the same error :) magic code "app.app_context().push()"

```
app = create_app()  
**app.app_context().push()**
if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all(app=create_app())
    app.run(debug=True) # run the flask app on debug mode
```